# A visual riddle about a figure

Tags: riddle, visual, knowledge, history

This is a visual riddle.
Each picture has something to do with who or what I am.

[image: The answer isn't written here :D]

If something about the picture is unclear, feel free to ask.

**Note:**

> The order of the numbers is random and doesn't matter towards the answer.

**Number 8 book titles if they are not readable:**

> The Alchemyst, The Magician, The Sorceress, The Necromancer

Can you **explain** with all numbers who or what I am and how they are related to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> Quetzalcoatl

1,

> The 'Zapotec' map where the worshiper of the god were found

2,

> Hernán Cortés claimed that the Aztec natives of Mexico thought him to be an emissary of the winged snake god

3,

> represented by the planet we know today as Venus

4,

> a ff8 summon

5,

> Just a reference to the wind god status?

6,

> Because Quetzel is often depicted as a serpent?

7,

> The black sun is associated with old Quetzy

8,

> He's also apparently a character in this book series which I think I may read...

Comment: Correct, can you find the others too? :) 
It was fast, what gave it away so quickly so I can make it a lil harder next time? I was always thinking that nr 6 would give it away. Nr 2 = Mesoamerica :)

Comment: I'm a big FF8 fan and a bit of a nerd so I already knew #3... I looked the others up to confirm.

Comment: tell me if you can't find the others, I'll fill em in then and accept this as answer.

Comment: How's that for filled in?  Feel free to add an OP explanation if it will clarify any of the connections (which it probably would).

Comment: I think that's as good as I can do on my explanations and I do feel that 5 and 6 are weak.  Fantastic question by the way. +1  Love these picture-puzzle-riddle things.  I'll have to have a go at putting one together when I get time.  You'd better have a go at solving it when I do! :)

Comment: Yup correct, 6 is: feathered serpent, more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feathered_Serpent